# libgdx Group is not affected by parent Table.row()

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to create in-game window, using Table class. But when i added groups of  images to that table, seems row() method has no influence to groups, they all are in the same place. Using Images instead of Groups works.
PS. I used Group to overlap images (kinda border for hover effect), don't know better way to do that.
Thanks

```
public class MyGroup extends Group{
        public  MyGroup(Image bg, Image thumb){
            this.addActor(bg);
            this.addActor(thumb);
        }
    }

public class ActionScreen extends Table {

 MyGroup[] group =new MyGroup[8];
for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
            group[i] =  new MyGroup(new Image(skin.getDrawable("item-bg")),new Image(skin.getDrawable("item-bg-over")));
            if (i==4){
                row();
                add(group[i]).top().padLeft(100);
            }
            else{
                add(group[i]).top().padLeft(100);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group's, by default, have zero size, so you have to manually set the size.

In your MyGroup constructor, you'd want to call something like this

```
this.setSize(bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight());
```